# How to add Vuejs component dynamically to the DOM

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I want to add a vue component to the DOM when an option is selected from the drop down list, so it's dynamically displayed

The code that I have tried is as follows

```
var html = "<component :is=\"dynamickeyvalue\"></component>";
$('#extraOptionsElements').html(html);
```

is there anyway to load the vue component when it's added as all I am getting now is blank.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `component` tag to load the component dynamically. The button click will simulate the component changing feature.

```
<template>

    <button 
        @click="changeComponent()"
    >Click me to change component</button>

    <component 
        :is="theSelectedComponent"
    ></component>

</template>
```

```
<script>
import Component1 from '@/components/Component1'
import Component2 from '@/components/Component2'
import Component3 from '@/components/Component3'
export default {
    components: {
        Component1,
        Component2,
        Component3
    },
    data () {
        return {
            theSelectedComponent: 'Component1'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changeComponent () {
            if (this.theSelectedComponent === 'Component1') {
                this.theSelectedComponent = 'Component2'
            } else if (this.theSelectedComponent === 'Component2') {
                this.theSelectedComponent = 'Component3'
            } else {
                this.theSelectedComponent = 'Component1'
            }
        }   
    }
}
</script>
```